# How to import namespaced packages for which sys.path needs to be adjusted?

Tags: python, python-2.6, import

In a python application I'm working on I would like to dynamically load packages (plugins) based on information provided at runtime (e.g. from a config file).

So, I change sys.path to add paths to the plugins I want to load, this generally works fine, but not if the plugin is a namespaced package inside a namespace which has already been initialized (I assume that is the problem anyway).

Example:

```
# lib1 contains plugins/__init__.py and plugins/foo/__init__.py
# lib2 contains plugins/__init__.py and plugins/bar/__init__.py
# plugins is a namespace package

import sys

sys.path.append ('lib1')
import plugins.foo

sys.path.append ('lib2')
import plugins.bar
```

The above code fails with an ImportError, presumably because the "import plugins.foo" line initialized the plugins namespace/package and no further attempt is made to search sys.path for other packages in the namespace.

If I change the code to this:

```
sys.path.append ('lib1')
sys.path.append ('lib2')
import plugins.foo
import plugins.bar
```

Both imports work, but I'd like to add to sys.path after the plugins.foo import.

So, my questions are:

1. Is my assumption correct that the second import fails because of the
   namespace package?
2. Is there a work-around?

Comment: You really don't need to mess with sys.path at all. Just use packages. For dynamic imports you can call the `__import__` function. Or use the `imp` module.

Comment: If I am following correctly, why not just not make ``plugins`` a package and add ``plugins/lib1`` and ``plugins/lib2`` to the path, then ``import foo`` and ``import bar``?

Comment: That said, I think your real question is how to make a plugin system in Python - see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417997/plugin-manager-in-python/7418304#7418304

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918898/prevent-python-from-caching-the-imported-modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your diagnosis is right. When you import `plugins.foo`, python also loads `plugins` and caches it in `sys.modules`. I haven't replicated your set-up, but I'd try  `del sys.modules['plugins']` before you import `bar`. If that doesn't work, try reloading `plugins`:

```
sys.path.append ('lib2')
import plugins
reload(plugins)
import plugins.bar
```

I must admit that reloading is, by general agreement, not a good idea in running programs. The "right" solution would be to figure out a workflow that lets you set the full `sys.path` before you start importing from the package. Or perhaps not to spread one package over different places.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with reload, that solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer, but an extended comment.**

The import situation as given in the original question above doesn't only arise when trying to import two different plugins. In our case we're trying to provide a local fallback for the case that a required Python package isn't installed in the current system.

The overall project structure for a MVE could look like this:

```
.
|-- src
|   `-- balla
|       |-- __init__.py
|       `-- hurga
|           `-- __init__.py
|-- src2
|   `-- balla
|       |-- __init__.py
|       `-- hurga2
|           `-- __init__.py
`-- test.py
```

, where `src/balla/__init__.py` and `src2/balla/__init__.py` have the same source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
try:
    import pkg_resources
    pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    from pkgutil import extend_path
    __path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

. The two `src/balla/hurga/__init__.py` and `src2/balla/hurga2/__init__.py` are empty for now. In our main script `test.py`:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'src'))

try:
    import balla.hurga2
except:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'src2'))
    import balla.hurga2
```

we first try to import the package "`balla.hurga2`" from the system directly, hoping that somebody installed it properly (e.g. via `pip`). The first `sys.path.append` in connection with the additional `src` folder, try to simulate the fact that other packages with the common namespace "balla" are installed (e.g. `balla.extended`). But `balla.hurga2` isn't present, so the declaration of the namespace "balla" is successful, but the actual import isn't. In the `except` path we now try to remedy this situation by inserting the local path to our fallback package "`src2`". On the new `import balla.hurga2` the old "balla" entry in the `sys.modules` dict is cached and remains unchanged. This results in the classical error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    import balla.hurga2
ImportError: No module named hurga2
```

By removing the cached entry for the "balla" package from `sys.modules` the problem can be solved:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'src'))

try:
    import balla.hurga2
except:
    if 'balla' in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules['balla']
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'src2'))
    import balla.hurga2
```

The additional if-clause is required for systems where no `balla` package at all is available.