# How to remove .py extension while using os.listdir

Tags: python, import, module, operating-system

In my code, I want to execute import filename for all the files that are present in a directory. I have a file `abc.py` under workspace.
I am currently doing the following :

```
for filename in os.listdir(homedir/workspace)
    exec "import " + filename
    filename = eval(filename + '.function(variable)')
```

The problem is that instead of doing import `abc`, it is doing import `abc.py`, and then showing the error `no module named py`

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: you should avoid `exec`. You can achieve exactly the same effect with: `module = __import__(filename)`. Using `exec` you are opening a security issue (e.g. someone can name a file `os;os.sytem("killall cats")` and when the code in your question executes all the cats will die! Using `__import__` you would only receive an `ImportError`. Even better than `__import__` is [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html), although it works in python2.7 and 3.1+ only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

```
os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
```

Of the returned two element array, the first element is just the filename, the second element is the extension. To be extra safe, you could double check that you did indeed grab a `.py` file:

```
if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == '.py':
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

To run `.function(variable)` for all Python files in a directory:

```
import os
import sys
from importlib import import_module

dirpath = 'homedir/workspace'
sys.path.append(dirpath)
for filename in os.listdir(path)
    module_name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext == '.py':
       try:
           result = import_module(module_name).function(variable)
       except Exception as e:
           sys.stderr.write('error: %s: %s\n' % (filename, e))
           continue
       else:
           print('%s: %s' % (filename, result))
```

See also [Building a minimal plugin architecture in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/932069/4279).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
import glob
import os
os.chdir("/mydir")
for file in glob.glob("*.py"):
    # do something with file
```

Read this to make sure You really want to use [`exec`](https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/)