# Python equivalent of Module::Pluggable

Tags: python

Perl has a very handy module named [Module::Pluggable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Module/Pluggable.html), which describes itself as:

> Module::Pluggable - automatically give your module the ability to have plugins

This is really useful for creating a plugin like architecture.

The key features it has are:

- searches for modules in a particular namespace.
- optionally instantiate each "plugin".
- provide an array of plugins for further use.

Is there anything equivalent for Python?

Comment: Normally, requests for libraries are strictly off-topic; instead of closing your post as off-topic, I instead dupe-closed you of a post where I explain how to use the `setuptools` infrastructure to handle plugin functionality. This is the Python ecosystem equivalent of `Module::Pluggable`.

Comment: Thanks - I had searched but hadn't come across that other post.

Comment: Should also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932069/building-a-minimal-plugin-architecture-in-python - I think this is far more relevant than the currently marked duplicate.