# Import from plugins

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, plugins, import

I am writing a [CLI-based web server control panel](https://github.com/dotancohen/burton) to which I am adding plugin support. I will need to import Python code files with arbitrary names from a `/plugins` directory. **How does one dynamically import code files from a particular directory?**

Consider the common situation in which we have the files `application.py` and `foobar.py`. In `application.py` we add the following code to run a method in `foobar.py`:

```
import foobar

foobar.main()
```

**How might I generalize this so that all files in the `plugins` directory get imported?**

Additionally, I will need to add a menu item "Run foobar plugin" so I will need a list of the plugin names to iterate over. **How is this done in Python?**

I am targeting Python 3 on Linux servers if that matters.

Comment: have you taken a look at [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) ?

Comment: @DavidK-J: Thank you. I've tried using `importlib.import_module()` and `importlib.__import__()` directly, but I could not figure out how to import a file in a subdirectory and scope its methods methods. I tried using a known filename in the directory, with the plan of getting the filenames via `os.walk()`. Can you post an example of imorting a Python file **in a subdirectory**? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [PluginBase](http://pluginbase.pocoo.org/) or the Stack Overflow [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932069/building-a-minimal-plugin-architecture-in-python).

Comment: Thanks for that link to the SO thread. I'm surprised that I did not find that either in the SO search or from Google.