# Are there any unused symbols in python?

Tags: python, character, artificial-intelligence, symbols

I am writing an AI that runs commands off of text file modules. In the folder in which my python program is located are a group of text files. They each have sets of keyword-command sets formatted like this:

*keyword 1,function 1|keyword 2,function 2*

My program loops through all these files and creates a list of keyword-command sets. For example, from 2 text files,

*keyword 1,function 1|keyword 2,function 2* and *keyword 3,function 3*,

the list generated is

*[['keyword 1', 'function 1'], ['keyword 2', 'function 2'], ['keyword 3', 'function 3']]*.

Now the *function* portions are commands run via the *exec* command, but I would like to have the ability to execute multiple lines of code for each function. I am thinking I will accomplish this by adding a special symbol to symbolize a new line and add the commands to a list, then iterate through them. My question is are there any symbol I could safely use that won't mess up any other commands that may use those symbols? For example, if I use *%*, it would mess up the modulo command.

Here is my code as of now in case you need it, although I don't really think you would.

```
# Setup
import os
import locale

# Load modules
functions = []
print(str(os.getcwd()))
print(str(os.getcwd().replace('ZAAI.py', '')))
for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd().replace('ZAAI.py', '')):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        openFile = open(os.getcwd().replace('ZAAI.py', '') + file, encoding=locale.getpreferredencoding())
        openFileText = openFile.read()
        print(openFileText)
        for item in openFileText.split('|'):
            functions.append(item.split(','))
print(functions)
```

Comment: Use a more powerful, flexible, and well-established format to store your data, like JSON. Don't do hacks like this.

Comment: Have you considered using an existing serialisation format, such as XML, YAML or JSON?  It might also be possible to use one of the `pickle` formats.  Having said that, the multi-byte symbols in Unicode are generally unused, a snowman for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, python supports multiple expressions/statements on a single line using a semi-colon `;`

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = a + b; print c
```

So, you don't need to create your own newline symbol to handle multiline python scripts.  That being said, you should probably not do this.

You're essentially creating a somewhat limited plugin architecture.  People have done this before.  There are **lots** of [options for doing this in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/932069/1547004).  I can just imagine the amount of frustration someone could have looking at one of your "plugin" files with dozens of commands, each with a 30 line python script on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation on literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters), The `$` and `?` characters are not used in Python for any purpose other than string literals and comments.

Comment: @cdarke Which are string literals.

Comment: In addition, they  can be escaped as `\x24` and `\x3f` respectively.